# JavaScript ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting below exception when ajax post.can any help me as below

The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: without your code how can we see whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the contentType that you are calling for in the ajax post configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax in this way :

```
  data = {}
  data['a'] = "aaaa";
  data['b'] = "bbbbbbbb"; 

  $.ajax({
      url: "url",
      data: data,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(result){
          //result is the output data sent from server
      },error: function(err){
          // This function will be called if error
      }  

  });
```